# Infinite eigenvectors for eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

There is given matrix $M = \left(\begin{array}{rr}1.1 & -1
\\
-1 & 1.1
\end{array}\right) $ ; Task is to compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $M$. I've computed eigenvalues using $\det M' = \det (M - \lambda I) = 0 $ criteria, and results: $\lambda_1 = 2.1$, $\lambda_2 = 0.1$ are equals to my MATLAB computation, which seems fine. I've tried to get eigenvectors for these eigenvalues, and, well, it seems that there is infinite number of these vectors, $\vec u_1 = [x,-x]; x \in R$; $\vec u_2 = [x,x]; x \in R $, as $M\vec u_i= \lambda_i \vec u_i$ is true for every real number.

Is this case possible or am I just using criterias wrong way?

Comment: Yes you should find an infinite number of these vectors and you can choose one of them e.g.
$$u_1=(1,-1)^T\qquad;\qquad u_2=(1,1)^T$$

Comment: An eigenvector is just a representative of a 1-dimensional *eigenspace* of other vectors that could also be chosen as representatives. For any eigenvector $x$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, for any scalar $\mu$, $M(\mu x)=\mu(Mx)=\mu(\lambda x)=\lambda(\mu x)$, so $\mu x$ is also an eigenvector (unless $\mu=0$).

Comment: The eigenvectors are given by $\ker (M-\lambda I)$ which is a subspace.

Comment: It would be instructive to determine the eigenvalues/vectors for this matrix without MATLAB or determinants or characteristic polynomials. It is $(1.1)A - B$ for matrices $A$ and $B$ whose eigenvectors are shared and can be easily described.

Answer (score 0):

As you get two distict eigenvalues, so Their geometric multiplicities are 1 each. This means that eigen space corresponding to these eigen values is One dimensional.
So you have infinte points which lie on a line, that can be eigen vectors